# How to make a trigger in ORACLE PL/SQL to not allow double values?

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I've a table named cliente with columns: COD_CLIENTE, CPF_CLIENTE and NAME_CLIENT.

How to make a TRIGGER in PL SQL to not allow insert or update double CPF_CLIENTE's values?

I've tryied:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER TG_CPF
  BEFORE INSERT ON CLIENTE
  FOR EACH ROW
DECLARE 
  CONDITION_CHECK NUMBER;
BEGIN
  SELECT COUNT(CPF_CLIENTE) INTO CONDITION_CHECK FROM CLIENTE WHERE CPF_CLIENTE = :new.CPF_CLIENTE;
  IF CONDITION_CHECK > 0 THEN
    RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR (-20000, ' CPF is Already in DB.');
  END IF;
END;
/
```

But i got:

```
ORA-20000:  CPF is Already in DB.
ORA-06512: at "USER.TG_CPF", line 6
ORA-04088: error during execution of trigger 'USER.TG_CPF'
```

Why I'm getting ORA-06512 and ORA-0488 errors?

The trigger does what i need. Don't insert/update the value if already exits, but i'm getting these 2 errors.

How to fix it, please?

Thank you!

Comment: Perhaps you are looking to add a unique constraint on cpf rather than creating a trigger.

Comment: I know i can use a constraint, but its for school and i can't do it =( I really need a trigger to check if cpf is already in db. If its is, it shows a error and not insert the cpf in the db...

Comment: You get the errors because you throw exception with `raise_application_error`. `06512` and `04088` are part of the full stack trace reported by Oracle and can't be avoided. Google and Oracle documentation are your friends.

Comment: A trigger will not help you here. You need a unique constraint.

Comment: @user272735 You're right, thank you! I've already read about, but i was thinking that maybe have some way to hide those 2 errors, but it's ok. The procedure is working fine ;) I really don't understand why a high school's teacher want an trigger to do it =/ Very bad and unuseful example :P

Comment: Please note, when you add more than a single row, then you will get an `ORA-04091: table USER.TG_CPF is mutating` error. See here: [Why am I NOT getting a mutating table error in trigger?](http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/29244/why-am-i-not-getting-a-mutating-table-error-in-trigger)

Comment: Is there any way to catch only the ORA-20000 part of the exception and display it?

Comment: maybe the teacher lacks understanding...  it is actually possible with a PRAGMA AUTONOMOUS_TRANSACTION - but not recommended.  the unique constraint is the way to enforce this.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot have a trigger on a table, and read data from that same table in the trigger body, when it's a row level trigger.

Instead, you need to use a unique constraint.